# GitLab Matter Most - Single Sign On broken

Tags: oauth, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, mattermost

I am getting the below error when trying to use SSO for mattermost with gitlab. How do you enable OAuth2 in Gitlab?

```
GitLab Mattermost needs your help:

The system admin has turned off OAuth2 Service Provider.
Go back to Mattermost
```

My /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb looks like this -

```
mattermost_external_url 'http://url/'
mattermost['gitlab_enable'] = true
mattermost['gitlab_id'] =  "code123"
mattermost['gitlab_secret'] = "code456"
mattermost['gitlab_scope'] = ""
mattermost['gitlab_auth_endpoint'] = "http://url/oauth/authorize"
mattermost['gitlab_token_endpoint'] = "http://url/oauth/token"
mattermost['gitlab_user_api_endpoint'] = "http://url/api/v3/user"
```

Answer (score 0):

I enabled `mattermost['service_enable_oauth_service_provider'] = true`, but it gave me a different error. Maybe this is all you need.